# Publish webservice reference issue

Tags: .net, iis, publish

For some reason during publish web application to IIS server I'm getting reference error as following:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DataStoreLoader' or
>   one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an
>   incorrect format.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file
>   or assembly
>   'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DataStoreLoader' or
>   one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an
>   incorrect format.

Here is what I've tested:

```
1. Remove obj/, bin/ directories from project to make sure build will be clear build
2. Rebuild solution and run using VS
3. Application works on IIS Express
4. Stop debug session
5. Publish application to IIS
6. Not working, assembly issue
7. Try to run again with debug session
8. Assembly issue
```

I'm confused.

Comment: Look at the advanced settings of the application pool that is running under. Set Allow 32 bit applications to true ands see if that solves it.

Comment: Application is 64bit with 64bit libraries so it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Well apparently changing Application Pool to allow 32 bit application to true (as mentioned in comment) worked well. First I wasn't sure about that answer because IIS instance for some reason was disabling my Application Pool right after I tried to access it. It was because of wrong configured IIS. As soon as I realized that I've found an answer here:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12287423/cant-load-a-site-in-iis8-on-32bit-pool-winsrv-2012-and-sharepoint-2013
```

Thanks @Crowcoder for good advice!